# Use multiple .wxs files to create .msi in a GitHub workflow (WiX Toolset)

Tags: github, wix, github-actions, windows-installer, wix3.11

I want to create an .msi file using the WiX Toolset within a GitHub Action. Since I generate a .wxs file (`Components.wxs`) using the "heat" command, I have two files (`Components.wxs` and `Product.wxs`) that need to be used during compilation. Unfortunately, the reference to the `Components.wxs` file is not working.

The Components.wxs file look kinder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Fragment>
        <DirectoryRef Id="PATH">
            <Component Id="SOMEDLL.dll" Guid="*">
                <File Id="SOMEDLL.dll" KeyPath="yes"
                      Source="SourceDir\SOMEPATH" />
            </Component>
        </DirectoryRef>
    </Fragment>
<Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="Components">
            <ComponentRef Id="SOMEDLL.dll" />
    </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
```

Initially, I attempted to directly use a `ComponentGroupRef` with the respective Id from the `Components.wxs` file within my Product tag in the `Product.wxs`.

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" 
     Title="Setup" 
     Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components" />
</Feature>
```

However, this consistently resulted in the error `Product.wxs(21) : error LGHT0094 : Unresolved reference to symbol 'WixComponentGroup:Components' in section 'Product:*'.`

Subsequently, I tried adding the following tag to the `ItemGroup` section in the Setup.wixproj: `<Compile Include="Components.wxs" />`. However, this did not bring about any changes.

Now, I attempted to include a `.wxi` file in the project, which is included in the `Product.wxs` and references the `ComponentGroup` in the `Components.wxs` file. Unfortunately, I encountered an error stating that the `ComponentGroupRef` tag is not allowed.

IncludeComponents.wxi:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Include>
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components" />
</Include>
```

In the Product.wxs:

```
<Feature Id="ProductFeature" 
     Title="Setup" 
     Level="1">
    <ComponentGroupRef Id="Components" />
</Feature>
```

Error: `IncludeComponents.wxi(3) : error CNDL0005 : The Wix element contains an unexpected child element "ComponentGroupRef".`

Here is the run-block in the GitHub action:

```
run: |
  cd Setup
  C:\wix\heat.exe dir ..\publishData -ag -dr PublishData -srd -sfrag -suid -cg Components -out Components.wxs
  C:\wix\candle.exe -ext C:\wix\WixIIsExtension.dll -ext C:\wix\WixUIExtension.dll Components.wxs Product.wxs 
  C:\wix\light.exe Product.wixobj -ext C:\wix\WixIIsExtension.dll -ext C:\wix\WixUIExtension.dll -out MySetup.msi
```

I have no idea why this is not working, and after a day, I've reached the limit of my patience. Can someone please tell me how to properly reference another `.wxs` file within the `Product.wxs` file?
Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the error**. In the `light` command the `Components.wixobj` had to be included before the `Product.wixobj`.

Comment: The order doesn't matter. You just need both files.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that this line in your .wixproj does not seem to be finding this file:

```xml
<Compile Include="Components.wxs" />
```

You don't provide enough information to know why that file is not found, but (assuming WiX v3) you need two `Compile` items in your .wixproj:

```xml
<ItemGroup>
  <Compile Include="Products.wxs" />
  <Compile Include="the\correct\path\to\the\Components.wxs" />
</ItemGroup>
```

What you are attempting to do with the Include file (`.wxi`) is confusing you. You don't need and should not use Include files.

Comment: First of all thank you for the help. However, I don't think it's the fault, because the `Components.wxs` is in the same directory as the `.wixproj` file. Could it be the command itself `C:\wix\candle.exe -ext C:\wix\WixIIsExtension.dll -ext C:\wix\WixUIExtension.dll Components.wxs Product.wxs ` is wrong? Must the `.wixproj` also be specified there?

Comment: MSBuild.exe, not candle.exe, interprets the .wixproj. Editing the .wixproj will have no effect. Your candle.exe command-line could be correct but the error is coming from light.exe. You should edit your question to be clear about how you are building.

Comment: ohh man, you are right. The `light` command is wrong, not the `candle` command. I've been looking for it wrong all along. I will add the complete `run` block to my question. Sorry